# Pentaho DI Transformation with transformation executor step fails during remote execution

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I am trying to remotely execute my transformation .The transformation has a transformation executor step with reference to another transformation from the same repository. Upon remote execution with export of resources the execution fails with the following message

Unable to load transformation due to error

The error is not stated . The executor step fails to initialize in remote execution.

Is this a bug?

Comment: Does it work locally?

Answer (score 1):

The issue is possibly due to wrong path to the transformation. Check if you have given the correct path to your transformation in the step.

Ideally use the system variable to set up your path. Check the below image:

[image]

The variable `${internal.Transformation.Filename.Directory}/<your ktr file>` automatically detects the path of your main transformation. Use this instead of giving the exact path.

For more read this [wiki](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.07+Variables).

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer.
I m actually using Repository by name 
And Repository by reference 
The repository is on the remote DI server and my spoon is always connected to the repository.

What I found with debugging is that the TransExecutor step
Checks for Repository by name and Repository by reference but in both cases the repository object rep is null .

Internally Repository by refernce throws NPE and Repository by name throws FileNotFoundException as it looks for ktr file in the file system instead of Repository.
I guess I must find out more on if this is a bug

Comment: For future reference, responses like this should be added as an edit to your question and/or as a comment to the existing answer (Rishu's).

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same issue. I fixed it using absolute path with placeholder pointing out to **Parent Job Repository Directory**

So **Transformation Executor** field **File name** looks like this:

```
[${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}/my-transformation.ktr][1]
```